# Not receiving the "ready" event when connection to Discord websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm currently trying to make a node.js program that connects to the Discord API and is able to provide a server count for my bot. I've already asked a few questions on this topic, so check my account if you're interested in that. Currently, the program can connect to the gateway, heartbeat, and receive `GUILD_CREATE` and `GUILD_DELETE` events, so that part is all working. Currently, I'm trying to work on reconnect and resume functionality for when the gateway inevitably gets disconnected. In the Discord API docs, it says that a session ID used for reconnecting is included in the Ready event, which is sent "after the initial handshake," however I'm not seeing any sort of Ready event sent.

The sequence of events I'm getting is:

1. I'm requesting a URL to connect to with an XMLHttpRequest and getting a response
2. I'm connecting to the URL and receiving a 'connect' event
3. An opcode 10 "Hello" message is sent by the API
4. I start heartbeating with the server
5. I send an opcode 2 "Identify" to the server
6. I receive the first opcode 11 heartbeat ack.
7. I begin to receive `GUILD_CREATE` events as guilds become, then all other events after that

Nowhere in this sequence of events is a "Ready" being sent, or at least not that I'm picking up. I tried logging every single piece of data I received, but still no "Ready." Does anyone know where the "Ready" falls in my sequence of events or what I need to do to see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was one of my `if` statements not logging the data when they needed to and skipping the "Ready." I managed to solve the issue by changing the order of them to get all my events to log properly.